# How can I call a Python instance's unspecific method by its member function name?

Tags: python, function, member

```
class worker:
    def foo(self):
        pass
    def foo1(self):
        pass
    def foo2(self)
        pass
```

The worker instance will have several `foo*` format member function(the number of `foo*` function is not known,because it is provided by other developers. How can I write a function to call all worker's foo* member function without modified it when user add new foo* function?

I can get all worker instances function name list by call `dir()`,but its element is str, I could not get worker instance run just by a string value. how could i solve this?

Comment: what do you need to do this for?

Comment: I want to write a test frame work,when others import the module,the will subchild worker and write many test cases as they need.then the module will try to call all foo* function

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access arbitrary attributes from an instance. Use the [`dir()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to list all (inherited) attributes on a class. Combining these makes:

```
foo_attributes = [attr for attr in dir(instance) if attr.startswith('foo')]
for name in foo_attributes:
    attr = getattr(instance, name)
    if callable(attr):
        attr()
```

I used the [`callable()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) here to make sure that the attribute is indeed a method.

Quick demonstration:

```
>>> class worker:
...     def foo(self):
...         print "Called foo"
...     def foo1(self):
...         print "Called foo1"
...     def foo2(self):
...         print "Called foo2"
... 
>>> instance = worker()
>>> foo_attributes = [attr for attr in dir(instance) if attr.startswith('foo')]
>>> for name in foo_attributes:
...     attr = getattr(instance, name)
...     if callable(attr):
...         attr()
... 
Called foo
Called foo1
Called foo2
```